# Should I Have Answered This (Now Closed) Question?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

I recently answered [Clean list of strings that are included on the own strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916585/clean-list-of-strings-that-are-included-on-the-own-strings/23920049#23920049), which is now closed as unclear. While I certainly agree that the question is not particularly well written (mostly due to non-native-English-speaker type issues), I didn't find it all that hard to understand. Additionally, it's not an obvious duplicate, and my answer (IMAO) demonstrates some interesting shell features and is potentially useful to other people.

I've been trying to follow the various discussions about question quality, but I'm basically a newb here, so my question is this: by answering that question, did I contribute to the decline of SO?

Comment: If anything you demonstrated that with some effort and good reading comprehension, the question was answerable.  If the closers assert that the question was to vague to be answered, then you disproved that assertion with what is known in discrete mathematics as a disproof by counterexample.

Comment: Just another example of a valuable member of the site being afraid because of the so called "decline of SO"... you did good kid!

Comment: I think you did everything spot on. Welcome, please stick around and continue like this as long as you can.

Answer (score 35):

**Yes**, if you understood what the OP wanted then it was fine to answer it.  It would have been especially good if you had edited the question to clear things up for future readers.

Comment: The second sentence being the really important part. If it's useful for future readers then it's more than worth answering.

Comment: Yeah, I may get around to cleaning up the question itself at some point.

Comment: @AaronDavies, great, you're the one in the best position to do that, since you understood what he wanted.

Answer (score 12):

If a question is really unclear and hard to understand, and you take the time to go above and beyond what is expected of a reader and manage to parse out what the question is actually asking you should *edit the question to make it a clear question*.  *Then* answer it, after the question is a clear question.

Comment: @pnuts If you yourself aren't sure what a question is asking then you should be asking clarifying questions in comments to figure out what the question is asking, not answering it.

Comment: @pnuts Then the OP can roll back your edit and clarify why your changes are incorrect.  That still results in the question being clarified.

Comment: @pnuts The same general problem occurs when you answer a question with an incorrect assumption about what it means.  That's why you should be careful when doing either and make sure that you're very confident.

Comment: Its interesting. Today i recevied a letter that i shouldn't ask questions here , cause my previuos question was not answered. I see that forum changes its own rules almost every day. Maybe its better to make another list of rules for long time? Now its hard to understand what is right or wrong here...

Comment: I think this is _potentially_ poor advice, at least if applied without thought. It's a different task to clarify a question without changing the meaning (formatting, tweak wording) - to editing a question after having answered it and being entirely sure what "the problem" was (which may be completely different from the asked question, not so in this case). Editing the question, and then answering it runs the risk of _changing_ the meaning, possibly unintentionally, and answering something different than what the author meant.

Comment: @AD7six If you're not sure what the question is then you should be asking clarifying questions to figure out what the question is, not answering it.

Comment: @Lucky You shouldn't re-post *the same question* just because it's not answered.  There is no reason to not ask a *different* question just because a previous one wasn't answered.  And I don't see how *either* case is at all related to this question.

Comment: @Servy I disagree where you're practically certain of the problem and that means writing a comment along the lines of "I think the problem is x, can you check please?" instead of just writing an answer. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23660848/1) for illustration; was I able to identify the problem? yes. Was I absolutely certain it was the one-and-only cause of problems? no, there's always scope for error. Had I blindly updated the question to better describe the _actual_ problem it would be a disservice to the OP had I been wrong or missed something else.